# SimpleDateFormat Exception in Java

Tags: java, exception, simpledateformat

I am a beginner in programming.

I want my code to be formatted in this order dd-MM-yyyy.

If not throw an exception.

What do I need to do?

```
    public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
    this.Day = tag;
    this.Month = month;
    this.Year = year;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    if (day != sdf) {

    }
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Best just catch the exception and check what is says.

Comment: day is an int, sdf is a SimpleDateFormat, they will never be equal. Just what are you trying to do?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve? We can see the code, we can tell you why it won't compile, but we don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See [the answer by Dawood ibn Kareem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49969779/5772882).

Comment: If you are writing your own `Date` class, I don’t think you need to format the date in the constructor (unless it’s an assignment that tells you to). A better design is to provide a method that does it when called, or just put it into the `toString` method.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you should use the `LocalDate` class, which is the Java 8 way of storing a day month and year.  And since you're asking about formatting, I guess you're interested in using a `DateTimeFormatter` and returning your value as a `String`.

```
public String formatDate(int day, int month, int year) {
    LocalDate theDate = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
    DateTimeFormatter theFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return theFormatter.format(theDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be useful

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Date1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            Date strdate1 = sdf.parse("19-04-2018"); //target1 date
            Date strdate2 = sdf.parse("02-04-2017"); //target2 date
            if (strdate2.before(strdate1)) {
                System.out.println("not outdated");
            } else {
                System.out.println("outdated");
            }
        } catch(ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn’t really answer the question. The question is about formatting, not parsing.